# Bloquear função PrintScreen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Sei que pergunta é polêmica, mas quero saber se realmente tem como bloquear a função *print screen* por completo. No Windows Forms tem como apagar a área de transferência com o clipboard.clear, mas já em JavaScript isso não é permitido por questões de segurança. Então isso realmente em ambas as situações e plataformas não é possível fazer, né?

Comment: Com Javascript puro não dá, exatamente pela razão que você mencionou. Você teria que usar algum plugin.

Comment: Não é possível bloquear totalmente a capacidade do usuário de capturar o conteúdo da tela, qualquer que seja a linguagem (já que o usuário pode simplesmente tirar um foto da tela com seu celular, certo?). Além disso, exceto em contextos muito específicos, modificar o funcionamento do ambiente do usuário (fora do software em si) é uma prática extremamente controversa, pois é invasivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode desativar a tela agarrando a partir do navegador da Web, ele só seria possível através da instalação de software adicional no PC do usuário.

Há alguns IRM (Information Rights Management) ferramentas disponíveis que fazem isso por exemplo, proteger chamadas de API do Windows / DirectX e também o monitoramento de memória de vídeo, como o Oracle IRM ou como a tecnologia IRM da Microsoft .

Especialmente o último pode ser de interesse como há também um complemento do Rights Management para Internet Explorer .

Mas, como outros já disse, qualquer tecnologia IRM / DRM controvérsias e você deve entender que na maioria das vezes vai limitar ou irritar seus usuários.

Fonte :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we

Answer (score 0):

Será que algo do assim não funcionaria?

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44) return false;
});
```

Comment: Print Screen sem a página selecionada fura esse método.

Comment: Verdade, além disso o evento e disparado no keyup, ai a tecla ja foi pressionada e o print feio :(

Comment: E se o usuário for um adolescente de 12 anos desocupado, ele pode simplesmente executar um `$().unbind()`.

Comment: Já tentamos assim. Realmente é complicado esta questão, mas outra ideia seria bloquear o acesso ao teclado e não deixar ele acionar nenhuma tecla, mas se o rapaz mexer no navegador, nas configurações, pode falhar esta ideia.