# Limpar área de transferência com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde pessoal!

Preciso limpar a área de transferência para que o usuário não dê print screen das telas do sistema, alguém conhece um script que funcione "cross browser"?

Comment: Você não pode fazer isso. Isso não é um recurso do navegado e sim do sistema operacional. Você pode fazer algumas coisas como jogar um texto qualquer na área de transferência, mas isso não garantirá que o usuário tire um print da tela e ele, o usuário, poderá muito bem abrir uma ferramenta de captura de tela do seu sistema operacional como o do Windows o SnippingTool.

Comment: Sim, eu sei que os usuários podem utilizar um software para captura de tela, porém no caso da plataforma que trabalho acredito que 99,9% desconheça estas ferramentas.

Comment: Mas até um ogro qualquer, se colocar na cabeça que quer tirar um print, ele vai atrás de como fazer; ou procurando um amigo nerd ou pesquisando no Google. :) OU tirando uma foto com o celular.

Comment: Mais explicações sobre o problema aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39311/bloquear-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-printscreen

Comment: Cara foi uma determinação do meu chefe, o cara não quer saber se o ogro vai procurar como imprimir ou não.